# @Transaction annotation is not woring with spring jdbctemplate

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am using spring 3.0.5 version. I am doing just simple test program to test the behavior of transaction but not getting. I have programmed three layer architecture project. In which dao layer contain following line of code.

```
@Repository("commonDao")
@Transactional
public class CommonDaoImpl implements CommonDao {
    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(CommonDaoImpl.class);
    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
@Autowired
    public void setSessionFactory(){
        jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }
    @Override
    public Object makePayment(Object e) {
            String sql = "insert into payment (id, name, amount) values('abc', 100)";
                return new NullPointerException();
    }
@Override
    public Object signUp(Object e) {
            String sql = "insert into login (userid, password) values('naveen', 'password')";
            return jdbcTemplate.update(sql);
    }
}
```

Service Layer looks like this.

```
@Service
public class CommonServiceImpl implements CommonService {   

    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(CommonServiceImpl.class);

    @Autowired
    private CommonDao commonDao;

//  I tried both of them one by one but not worked
    @Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED, rollbackFor=Exception.class)
    @Override
    public boolean makePayment(HttpServletRequest request) {
        WebApplicationContext ctxt = WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(request.getServletContext());
        commonDao.signUp(new Object());
        commonDao.makePayment(new Object());    
        return true;
    }

}
```

controller looks like this

```
@RequestMapping("/doPayment")
    public void doPayment(HttpServletRequest request){
        logger.info("controller");
        WebApplicationContext ctxt = WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(request.getServletContext());
        commonService.makePayment(request);
    }
```

dispatcher-servlet.xml file

```
      <context:component-scan base-package="com" />
        <!--    <context:annotation-config /> -->
    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test" />
        <property name="username" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="password" />
    </bean>
<!-- Add this tag to enable annotations transactions -->
<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>
```

web.xml file contains

```
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
               org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
 <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <context-param>   
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
        </listener-class>
  </listener>
```

its very simple program. In which service layer called two methods of dao signup and makePayment under transaction. Signup method executing successfully but makePayment throw an exception. Now the problem is because both method executing under transaction so there will be not operation happen against database. But in login table data is inserted whereas payment table is empty. But as per my understanding towards transaction none of entry should be inserted into a database. Can some one help me what's going.

```
Invoking request handler method: public void com.controller.CommonController.doPayment(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
controller
Using transaction object [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager$DataSourceTransactionObject@1b7379b]
Creating new transaction with name [com.service.CommonService.makePayment]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW,ISOLATION_DEFAULT,-throwable
Creating new JDBC DriverManager Connection to [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test]
Acquired Connection [com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection@74b8d3] for JDBC transaction
Switching JDBC Connection [com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection@74b8d3] to manual commit
Bound value [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.ConnectionHolder@6a56c0] for key [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource@25a0f5] to thread [http-bio-8080-exec-14]
Initializing transaction synchronization
Getting transaction for [com.service.CommonService.makePayment]
Executing SQL update [insert into login (userid, password) values('naveen', 'password')]
Retrieved value [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.ConnectionHolder@6a56c0] for key [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource@25a0f5] bound to thread [http-bio-8080-exec-14]
Retrieved value [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.ConnectionHolder@6a56c0] for key [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource@25a0f5] bound to thread [http-bio-8080-exec-14]
SQL update affected 1 rows
Retrieved value [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.ConnectionHolder@6a56c0] for key [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource@25a0f5] bound to thread [http-bio-8080-exec-14]
Completing transaction for [com.service.CommonService.makePayment]
Triggering beforeCommit synchronization
Triggering beforeCompletion synchronization
Initiating transaction commit
Committing JDBC transaction on Connection [com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection@74b8d3]
Triggering afterCommit synchronization
Triggering afterCompletion synchronization
Clearing transaction synchronization
Removed value [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.ConnectionHolder@6a56c0] for key [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource@25a0f5] from thread [http-bio-8080-exec-14]
Releasing JDBC Connection [com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection@74b8d3] after transaction
Returning JDBC Connection to DataSource
Invoking afterPropertiesSet() on bean with name 'action/doPayment'
Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.aop.support.DefaultBeanFactoryPointcutAdvisor#0'
Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.aop.support.DefaultBeanFactoryPointcutAdvisor#0'
Rendering view [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView: name 'action/doPayment'; URL [/WEB-INF/pages/action/doPayment.jsp]] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'
Forwarding to resource [/WEB-INF/pages/action/doPayment.jsp] in InternalResourceView 'action/doPayment'
Successfully completed request
```

when i saw the log file it is using the transaction instance. can some help to come out this problem.

Comment: Where is the config for your `jdbctemplate`?

Comment: Did you add the annotation transaction flag to you config?

Comment: Does the method which calls the two dao methods start the transaction, i.e. did you annotate the method with `@transactional`?

Comment: First Q -Please see the dao layer.where jdbctemplate autowired. Second @Transactional annotation is added on service method not on dao methods

Comment: What is commonService? The problem could be that the transaction on service doesn't start. Update your question whit commonService definition.

Comment: I have edited question with full code of commonservice. commonserive is a sevice layer of mvc. and for more information you can see the log where transaction started perfectly and commit too for login table. But it should not be inserted because in second dao method(makePayment) throw an execution inside undergoing transaction.

Comment: Try to check if your method makePayment run inside a transaction.   TransactionSynchronizationManager.isActualTransactionActive(). Moreover add <tx:annotation-driven proxy-target-class="true"/> in your configuration

Comment: Add this intead the first one <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager"/>